# Execute method Async Task

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I am not sure if this question has been asked on SO before. When executing an async task using `myTask.execute();` what method runs at the very beginning. I am following this tutorial: http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/consuming-json-services-android-apps for consuming JSON services and the author is using `new ReadWeatherJSONFeedTask()
                .execute()` along with some parameters. I am confused as to which method runs first and how the parameter are being passed along to get the result.
Can anyone help me.

Thanks.!

Comment: The parameters are there because somebody decided to use _inheritance_ by _extending_ the class _AsyncTask_.  When you extend a class, you can add your own member variables to achieve new functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Android API Reference AsyncTask,

> When an asynchronous task is executed, the task goes through 4 steps:
>
> 1. onPreExecute(), invoked on the UI thread before the task is executed. This step is normally used to setup the task, for instance
>    by showing a progress bar in the user interface.
> 2. doInBackground(Params...), invoked on the background thread immediately after onPreExecute() finishes executing. This step is used
>    to perform background computation that can take a long time. The
>    parameters of the asynchronous task are passed to this step. The
>    result of the computation must be returned by this step and will be
>    passed back to the last step. This step can also use
>    publishProgress(Progress...) to publish one or more units of progress.
>    These values are published on the UI thread, in the
>    onProgressUpdate(Progress...) step.
> 3. onProgressUpdate(Progress...), invoked on the UI thread after a call to publishProgress(Progress...). The timing of the execution is
>    undefined. This method is used to display any form of progress in the
>    user interface while the background computation is still executing.
>    For instance, it can be used to animate a progress bar or show logs in
>    a text field.
> 4. onPostExecute(Result), invoked on the UI thread after the background computation finishes. The result of the background
>    computation is passed to this step as a parameter.

As this explains `onPreExecute()` on Ui Thread is executed at the very beginning.

This [Guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) might help you with more help in this regard.

Answer (score 4):

Parameters that the asyncTask needs, are declared while defining the class that extends asyncTask.. And the sequence of execution of methods is:

1. onPreExecute() ---it runs on the UI thread
2. doInBackground() and onProgressUpdate() -- they run on worker thread
3. and onPostExecute() --- runs on UI thread.